# Enable jQuery "$" symbol for a named function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

I'm working with Wordpress and jQuery, where I can only use the "$" symbol by passing it as a parameter into functions which are defined with "jQuery".

But I don't know how to pass in the symbol into a named function.

This didn't work:

```
(function sendPostRequest($){
    $("<input>").attr({
        type: "hidden",
        name: "merchant",
        value: 90198778
    }).appendTo('#signup_form');
})(jQuery);
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: This should work if jQuery is defined. Now in which context this snippet is called?

Comment: IMHO, it is quite unclear what you are asking: `But I don't know how to pass in the symbol into a named function`?

Comment: I like to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";});` and put all my code inside.

Comment: @A.Wolff Maybe I didn't ask it in the semantically perfect way, but I wanted to be able to use the $ symbol inside a named function (not anonymous), and not necessarily a "document ready" function.

Comment: Your best bet imho would be just to past `jQuery` as function parameter (as your IIFE is doing). And because you said `This didn't work` regarding posted snippet, i was quite confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
function sendPostRequest(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    ....
```