# How to make jquery use a named function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to do this for hours, and it's persisted in not working. I can't find why.

My HTML:

```
<label>
Description<br>
(<span id='fieldLength'>0</span> Chars. ±1):

<textarea name='dataDescr' id='metaDescr'>Some Text Here.</textarea>
</label>
```

What I have that **Does not work** . It does not give me any response, no console errors in firebug or any sort of feedback :

JQuery:

```
counterChecker = function() {
    var max = 800;
    var lengthVal = $('#metaDescr').val().length;
    var fl = $('#fieldLength');
    if (lengthVal >= max) {
        var char = lengthVal - max;
        fl.text('Over by ' + char);
    }
    else {
        fl.text(lengthVal);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#metaDescr').on("change", counterChecker() );
 });
```

> Edit: This also does not work if the function is set out within the
>   document ready brackets.

But what ***DOES*** work is the same code directly inserted into the `on change` function as an anonymous function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#metaDescr').on("change", function() {
        var max = 800;
        var lengthTwo = $(this).val().length;
        var lf = $('#fieldLength');
        if (lengthTwo >= max) {
            var char = lengthTwo - max;
            lf.text('Over by ' + char);
        }
        else {
            lf.text(lengthTwo);
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone help me understand why this difference?

Why doesn't it work as a separate called function and yet does not give any errors to my firebug, yet it can work as directly referenced (anonymous?) function . How can I make it behave as intended but keeping the code in a separate self contained functional unit.

I'm using JQuery 1.11.3 and viewing [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410263/enable-jquery-symbol-for-a-named-function) stackoverflow [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093192/how-to-create-a-jquery-function-create-a-new-jquery-method-or-plugin) over the last few hours hasn't shown the light :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#metaDescr').on("change", counterChecker() );`calls the `counterChecker` function and assigns the returned value to the onchange handler. In this case it returns undefined and uses that as the change listener. What you want is `$('#metaDescr').on("change", counterChecker);` which passes a refrence to the `counterChecker` function that will be called when the change event fires.

Comment: That works, thank you! I can't believe I've been going round this for hours and all it was was a pair of empty brackets. Grrrr .

Comment: Don't beat yourself up it's a common mistake that is hard to debug. You will see it a lot on SO in regards to setTimeout & setInterval.

Comment: I suspect it comes as well from me using a lot of PHP whose functions are defined as such by being followed by brackets. Also without the brackets I thought Javascript/JQuery was asking for a `var`iable